# Generate single CSV file with multiple JSON and with their respective headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-csv-import

I am trying to export csv with headers but the condition is that I have 3 json. All 3 json are downloded in same csv file. Now I want to differentiate these json by including headers in csv file. I have a JSON like :

```
"data": {
    "subData": [
        [
            {
                "ABC": "North America",
                "EFD": 937,
                "EFDPercentage": 66.5483,

            },
            {
                "ABC": "Europe",
                "EFD": 123,
                "EFDPercentage": 8.7358,

            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "PQR": "Media and Entertainment",
                "topPQR": 174,
                "PQRPercentage": 12.358,

            },
            {
                "PQR": "Sep 2016",
                "topPQR": 82,
                "PQRPercentage": 5.8239,

            },
            {
                "PQR": "Conference",
                "topPQR": 50,
                "PQRPercentage": 3.5511,

            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "XYZ": "M&E",
                "topXYZ": 279,
                "XYZPercentage": 19.8153,

            },
            {
                "XYZ": "Technology",
                "topXYZ": 197,
                "XYZPercentage": 13.9915,

            },
            {
                "XYZ": "Online Retail",
                "topXYZ": 163,
                "XYZPercentage": 11.5767,

            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

As we know ng-csv attribute only accept only one json object. So that I have concatenate 3 object into one big object by doing this:

```
$scope.subDataArr = [];
$scope.subData = response.data.subData;
for(var i=0; i<self.subData.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<self.subData[i].length; j++){
        self.subDataArr.push(self.subData[i][j]);
    }
}
```

So that all above data is merge into subDataArr in JSON object format. By accessing this object I can download all data into CSV file but I want to differentiate these data by giving headers in csv file. I know we are using csv-header to give heading in csv file. But here their are 3 different header list. So how can I use 3 different headers with their respective data?
Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem. I create new object which have headers name and push into main json object which we are downloaded. Like this:

```
$scope.subDataArr = [];
$scope.subData = response.data.subData;
for(var i=0; i<self.subData.length; i++){
    if(i===0){
        self.Header1 = {
                "ABC": "ABC",
                "EFD": "EFD",
                "EFDPercentage": "EFDPercentage"

            };
        self.subDataArr.push(self.Header1);
    }
    if(i===1){
        self.Header2 = {
                "PQR": "PQR",
                "topPQR": "topPQR",
                "PQRPercentage": "PQRPercentage"

            };
        self.subDataArr.push(self.Header2);
    }
    if(i===2){
        self.Header3 = {
                "XYZ": "XYZ",
                "topXYZ": "topXYZ",
                "XYZPercentage": "XYZPercentage"

            };
        self.subDataArr.push(self.Header3);
    }
    for(var j=0; j<self.subData[i].length; j++){
        self.subDataArr.push(self.subData[i][j]);
    }
}
```

So all data with theirs headers are come into main JSON and I get expected output :-)